# Ruby on Rails: hours worked this week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a "Log" project, each log has a :date, :hours, :description.  I am simply trying to determine how many hours I have worked in a week, but am having trouble determining the proper separation of code. Let me know if any further code is needed.  Rails 3.

**log.rb**

```
def self.days_in_range(from, to)
  Log.where(:date => (from.to_date)..(to.to_date))
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :sidebar do %>
<h4> Sidebar Content </h4>
<ul>
  <li>Hours worked this week:
    <%= Log.hours_this_week %> # unsure how to call
  </li>
  <li>Hours worked in total: 
    <%= Log.sum(:hours) %>
  </li>
  <li>Most hours worked in a day:
    <%= Log.maximum(:hours) %>
  </li>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

**logs_helper.rb?**

```
def hours_this_week
  today = Time.now
  day_of_week = today.wday
  sunday = today - day_of_week.days
  days = Log.days_in_range(today, sunday)
  hours = 0

  days.each do |day|
    hours += day.hours
  end

end
```

[solved] **error**

```
Showing /Users/***/Documents/workspace/***/hours_tracker/hours/app/views/logs/index.html.erb where line #33 raised:

undefined method `hours_this_week' for #<LogsController:0x103b66be8>
Extracted source (around line #33):

30:     <h4> Sidebar Content </h4>
31:     <ul>
32:         <li>Hours worked this week:
33:             <%= hours_this_week %>
34:         </li>
35:         <li>Hours worked in total: 
36:             <%= Log.sum(:hours) %>
Rails.root: /Users/***/Documents/workspace/***/hours_tracker/hours
```

[full trace](http://pastebin.com/NxX3Vfa0)

[updated] **new error**

**error**

```
ArgumentError in Logs#index

Showing /Users/***/Documents/workspace/***/hours_tracker/hours/app/views/logs/index.html.erb where line #33 raised:

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
Extracted source (around line #33):

30:     <h4> Sidebar Content </h4>
31:     <ul>
32:         <li>Hours worked this week:
33:             <%= hours_this_week %>
34:         </li>
35:         <li>Hours worked in total: 
36:             <%= Log.sum(:hours) %>
Rails.root: /Users/***/Documents/workspace/***/hours_tracker/hours
```

Comment: Is the helper method inside LogsHelper module?

Comment: yes it is however I am calling from my view, does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tangential to your question, but I noticed this looking at your `hours_this_week` method. I could be wrong, but one little thing you may want to look at here is that your `hours_this_week` method is going to return the collection iterated through in your `each` statement (i.e. `days`), not the product of that statement (the new value of `hours`).

You could either just add the line:

```
 hours
```

to the end of this method, or use `inject` instead of `each`:

```
# The initial "hours" declaration is no longer necessary,
# because inject returns its result, rather than the 
# collection it is iterating through.

days.inject(0) {|hours, day| hours += day.hours }
```

That line would eliminate the need for your `each` statement and for explicitly returning `hours` at the end of your `hours_this_week` method.

That said, putting the method in `logs_helper.rb` and calling it with:

```
<%= hours_this_week %>
```

would be the way to go.

Comment: `days.sum(&:hours)` is better :-)

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was looking at Ruby and forgot about ActiveRecord methods.

Comment: Me neither :-) It is an Array instance method. I thought it is in stdlib, but actually it is provided by Active Support.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `index.html.erb` file is in your `app/views/logs` folder, you can just call `hours_this_week` directly:

```
<%= hours_this_week %>
```

Comment: I get the following error when I do that: undefined method `hours_this_week' for #<LogsController:0x103af62d0>.  Also, is logs_helper.rb the appropriate file to write my method?

Comment: Is your `logs_helper.rb` file in `app/helpers`? Are you trying to call `hours_this_week` from within your actual controller, or from within your view?

Comment: You should call it exactly how @dmarkow wrote it, not with `<%= Log.hours_this_week %>`.

Comment: I am calling it from my view, do I need to construct a method in my controller? how would that look?

Comment: The error message you showed would indicate that somewhere in your `logs_controller.rb` file, you're trying to call `hours_this_week`. Can you update your original question with a full backtrace (all the lines below the error)?

Comment: You were correct @dmarkow, I had a stray call in my controller. Now I'm getting a ArgumentError in Logs#index: "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Comment: I figured it out -- I had to use 'days.sum(:hours)' and not 'days.sum(&:hours)'.  Thank you everyone for your help!